# How to pass bundle values between methods in Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am using the Zapier Legacy code and I have created a computed field inside the Authentication.
This computed field is updated with a value in the check_pre_roll method and I want to use the updated field on other upload and update methods but the value is null.
How can I save the new value in the bundle field (bundle.auth.location) from within the check_pre_roll method and then use it in any other pre/post-roll methods? The default value is null.

Comment: I think one issue here is that computed fields are only used to capture output from OAuth and session output test calls. I don't think this can be edited or updated outside of that.

Comment: Is there a way I can declare a global variable in Zapier legacy code which can be modified inside the method which will become the new value of the variable and when called in another method it will show the new value?